# Restkit 0.24.0: How to serialize objects (including to-many relationships) to JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, serialization, restkit

I have a core data datamodel that is quite a bit different from the one my API developer expects. (Due to the way the app works I cannot deviate from this)

I have simplified my managedObjectModels into the desired format using some custom classes

A convertor class that starts it all and delivers: (simplified for readability)

- a generalData class that holds the top level object
- a manyData class that represents the format of the to-many relationship objects within the GeneralData
- a otherData class that also holds to-many relationship objects within the generalData class but is unrelated to the manyData class.

These are the generalData attributes:

-(NSString*) ID
-(NSString*) name
-(NSString*) position
-(NSArray*) manyDataObjects
-(NSArray*) otherDataObjects

each manyData and OtherDataObject in their turn holds some basic attributes, their own ID, and the generalData ID.

I have added the following requestmapping to the generalData class:

```
+ (RKObjectMapping *)defineRequestMapping
{
RKObjectMapping * mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[generalData class]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                     @"generalID": @"generalID",
                                     @"generalName": @"generalName",
                                     @"generalPosition": @"generalPosition",
                                     @"generalManyData": @"generalManyData",
                                     @"generalOtherData": @"generalOtherData"
                                      }];

return mapping;
}
```

and run it like so:

```
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping =  [[generalData defineRequestMapping] inverseMapping];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:[RKRequestDescriptor
                               requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[generalData class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST]];
```

I have also added similar defineRequestMapping Class Methods to the manyData and OtherData classes.

Everytime I try to serialize the generalData class using Restkit I get an error telling me that it cannot serialize the unkown manyData class.If I comment the "generalManyData" and "generalOtherData" line it works and serializes the other 3 attributes into the body.

I cannot seem to find a tutorial to clear my mind and am at the moment kind of mindblocked at what to do next. I tried using a relationshipMapping but that didn't bring me any further. Perhaps I forgot something?

Comment: It sounds like there is an issue with the mappings you're setting up in the "manyData" and "otherData" classes. I couldn't say what without seeing code, but I'd set break points and make sure that the mapping is being set on those classes and that all the object mappings for those classes are configured correctly to start

Comment: Hm I'll look into it..Figured I got the JSONWrite error because it can't traverse into the manyData objects in the array. What would be the absolute correct way of setting up these nested mappings?

Comment: You should really show the interfaces (with properties) and the mappings for each of your classes. At the moment your property names and mapping names don't match...

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs for `RKRelationshipMapping`

You need to nest the RKRelationshipMapping object for your `generalManyData` within the mapping for your `generalObject` to establish the to-many relationship between the two classes. Simple string values won't work if there are nested objects.

```
RKObjectMapping *generalManyMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[generalData class]];];


[generalManyMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"generalManyData"

                           toKeyPath:@"generalManyData"

                         withMapping:@{@"propertyOne" : @"propertyOne", @"propertyTwo" : @"propertyTwo"}]];
```